# setting Primary key in Django model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have changed primary key in my model

```
class lab(models.Model):
    IP = models.CharField(max_length=250 , primary_key = True)
    PingStatus = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    SSHConnectivity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    SSHLogin = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    DeviceType = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    DeviceVersion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I am trying to make two entries by assigning two different "IP" values for lab object. But somehow only one object is there in model

```
>>> a=lab(IP="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(PingStatus="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(SSHConnectivity="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(SSHLogin="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(DeviceType="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(DeviceVersion="1.2.3.4")
>>> a.save()
>>> lab.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<lab: lab object>]>
>>> a=lab(IP="1.2.3.5")
>>> a=lab(PingStatus="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(SSHConnectivity="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(SSHLogin="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(DeviceType="1.2.3.4")
>>> a=lab(DeviceVersion="1.2.3.4")
>>> a.save()
>>> lab.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<lab: lab object>]>
>>> b=lab(IP="1.2.3.5")
>>> b=lab(PingStatus="1.2.3.4")
>>> b=lab(SSHConnectivity="1.2.3.4")
>>> 
>>> b=lab(SSHLogin="1.2.3.4")
>>> b=lab(DeviceType="1.2.3.4")
>>> b=lab(DeviceVersion="1.2.3.4")
>>> b.save()
>>> lab.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<lab: lab object>]>
>>>
```

Can someone check ? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create instance of the class and later set values for that instance, for example:

```
a = lab(IP="1.2.3.4")
a.PingStatus = "1.2.3.4"
a.save()
```

Creating instance with all parameters set at once should help too:

```
b = lab.objects.create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all of the values that you want at once, e.g.

`b = lab.objects.create(value1='xx', value2='yy', value3='zz')`

Also, you're not following conventions.  Your model name should be capitalized, and your field names should be snake_case.  For example,  lab -> Lab,  PingStatus -> ping_status

Comment: I tried this but I didn't use create   . This kind of syntax worked fine `row = lab(IP=information[0],PingStatus=information[1],SSHConnectivity=information[2],SSHLogin=information[3],\
               DeviceType = information[4],DeviceVersion = information[5])`